# How to create a Postgres column indicating if a row is referenced

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

I have a schema similar to

```sql
CREATE TABLE A(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  has_ref BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE B(
  f_id INTEGER REFERENCES A (id)
);
CREATE TABLE C(
  f_id INTEGER REFERENCES A (id)
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/224c86

`has_ref` is supposed to be `TRUE` if the row in `A` has a reference, and `FALSE` if not. There should only be at most one reference to each row in `A`.

Ideally, I would like this to happen automatically and be enforced by the database, so that e.g. if a row in `B` or `C` is deleted, `has_ref` would change back to `FALSE` in the referenced row.

I could not find a way to do this with triggers or constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than storing a `boolean`, store an `integer` column `refcount`.

Then add triggers on `b` and `c` that add or subtract from these values whenever a referencing row is added, removed or modified.

Comment: That would solve the problem of keeping these fields up to date, but it would not enforce their correctness like a constraint would. E.g `UPDATE`ing the `refcount` without changing `B` or `C` would be allowed.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot have a constraint for that. So there is no better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query to define it:

```
select a.*
       (exists (select 1 from b where b.f_id = a.id) or
        exists (select 1 from c where c.f_id = a.id)
       ) as has_ref
from a;
```

If you want to encapsulate this logic, you can create a view that calculates it on the fly.

Comment: That would only work in a `SELECT` though, right? I want this to be stored as part of the table and not be calculated on every query, as all the involved tables are quite large in production.

Comment: @NadavZingerman . . . Unfortunately, this is volatile data and to be accurate needs to be calculated on the fly.  If you only want a picture of the value when a row is inserted, you can write a trigger for the calculation.

Comment: I see. I was hoping for a solution that would store this data without re-calculating it each time.

Comment: @NadavZingerman . . . How can the data be "stored"?  The referenced tables could change and then the `has_cref` value would need to be changed.  You could implement that logic with a trigger, I suppose, but that seems more complicated, especially because the `exists` logic would be quite fast with indexes in the secondary tables.